# Cmd window keeps freezing when i am about to enter github password after git push operation

Tags: git, github

When I perform git push from my cmd window, it asks for github username and then github password.

Each time i when I want to enter github password , it keeps freezing.

Comment: Sorry, about asking this, but: Are you sure it keeps freezing or does it simply not display the characters you entered into the password dialog?

Comment: Its working very fine now. Its just that when you are typing the password it will not be displayed. If the password typed is correct and you press the enter key the error will not appear again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Switch to ssh keys and it will never ask you again to enter username password

---

#### How to set up ssh-keys under github?

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)
  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content

---

#### How to add sh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on your username top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Choose `Settings` | `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save

And you all set to go :-)

Comment: Its working now. It was'nt actually freezing. Its just that it will not display the password as you are typing.